employing Lagrangian coordinates in pdes
I have been trying to read and understand a thesis, but I got stuck here where they use a Lagrangian coordinate to solve PDEs.
The equations are:
Eq. 2.32:
$$
    \partial_t h(x,t) + \partial_x (h(x,t) u(x,t))=0  
    $$
Eq. 2.33:
$$
    \partial_x u(x,t) h(x,t)= T(t)
    $$
Eq. 2.34 and 2.35:
$$
    h(x,0) =h_0(x), u(0,t) =0, u(l(t),t) = \partial_t l(t), 
    $$
and then here they use a Lagrange coordinate to solve them:

Could someone please help me understand how to get relation 2.37 and later 2.40 in this image?

(2.41) is not contained in the image.

@Filippo thanks for pointing this out. I meant 2-40

There is no Eq. (2.40) in the image.

@Gonçalo Thank you so much for pointing this out. I renewed the picture


Let's derive the equation between $(2.36)$ and $(2.37)$. Using the chain rule, we have
$$
h_{\tau}=h_tt_{\tau}+h_xx_{\tau}. \tag{1}
$$
Now, we make the following substitutions in $(1)$: (i) $h_t=-(hu)_x$ [Eq. $(2.32)$]; (ii) $t_{\tau}=1$ (since $t=\tau$), and (iii) $x_{\tau}=u$ [Eq. $(2.36)$]; thus
$$
h_{\tau}=-(hu)_x+h_xu=-hu_x \implies h_{\tau}+hu_x=0. \tag{2}
$$
Using again the chain rule, we have
$$
u_{\xi}=u_xx_{\xi}+u_tt_{\xi}=u_xx_{\xi} \implies u_x=\frac{u_{\xi}}{x_{\xi}}, \tag{3}
$$
where we used the fact that $t_{\xi}=0.$ Substituting $(3)$ in $(2)$ we get
$$
h_{\tau}+\frac{h}{x_{\xi}}u_{\xi}=0. \tag{4}
$$

Using the fact that $u=x_{\tau}$, we can rewrite $(4)$ as
$$
\frac{h_{\tau}}{h}+\frac{x_{\xi\tau}}{x_{\xi}}=0 \implies \int_0^{\tau}\left(\frac{h_{\tau'}}{h}+\frac{x_{\xi\tau'}}{x_{\xi}}\right)d\tau'=0 
$$
$$
\implies \ln\left(\frac{h(\xi,\tau)}{h(\xi,0)}\right)+
\ln\left(\frac{x_{\xi}(\xi,\tau)}{x_{\xi}(\xi,0)}\right)=0. \tag{5}
$$
Since $x(\xi,0)=\xi$, we have $x_{\xi}(\xi,0)=1$; in addition, $h(\xi,0)=h_0(\xi)$, so Eq. $(5)$ becomes
$$
\ln\left(\frac{h(\xi,\tau)x_{\xi}(\xi,\tau)}{h_0(\xi)}\right)=0
\implies \frac{h(\xi,\tau)x_{\xi}(\xi,\tau)}{h_0(\xi)}=1, \tag{6}
$$
which is equivalent to Eq. $(2.37)$.

Substituting Eq. $(2.33)$ in Eq. $(2)$, we obtain
$$
h_{\tau}+T(\tau)=0 \implies h(\xi,\tau)-h(\xi,0)+\int_0^{\tau}T(\tau')\,d\tau'=0, \tag{7}
$$
which is equivalent to Eqs. $(2.38)$ and $(2.39)$, with $f(\tau):=\int_0^{\tau}T(\tau')\,d\tau'$.

Finally, combining Eqs. $(2.37)$ and $(2.38)$ and integrating with respect to $\xi$, we obtain Eq. $(2.40)$:
$$
l(\tau):=x(1,\tau)-x(0,\tau)=\int_0^{1}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\xi}\,d\xi
=\int_0^{1}\frac{h_0(\xi)}{h(\xi,\tau)}\,d\xi
=\int_0^{1}\frac{h_0(\xi)\,d\xi}{h_0(\xi)-f(\tau)}.
$$


